# Json Reflaction warning with custom List

Tags: java, android, json

I am trying to reflect a `json` to class. But i have problem when i have `JsonArray` inside of `JsonArray` with object's.  It seems that is trying to find a class like `List<Step>` but cannot found.

My output is :

> W/System.err: Value ... at steps of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

My class is like:

```
class Step {
  private Consecutive consecutive;
  private List<List<Steps>> steps = null;
}
```

a part of my Json :

```
{"step":{"consecutive":{"enabled":true,"period":"day"},"steps":[[{"points":100},{"points":200},{"points":300},{"points":400}],[{"points":100},{"points":200},{"points":300},{"points":400}],[{"points":100},{"points":200},{"points":300},{"points":400}],[{"points":100},{"points":200},{"points":300},{"points":400}],[{"points":100},{"points":200},{"points":300},{"points":400}],[{"points":100},{"points":200},{"points":300},{"points":400}],[{"points":100},{"points":200},{"points":300},{"points":400}]]}}
```

My Json Parser :

```
public static Object populateObjectFromJSON(Class<?> classname, JSONObject js) {
    Object obj = null;
    System.out.println("Populating " + classname.getSimpleName() + " -with- " + js.toString());
    try {
        obj = classname.newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException e1) {
        System.err.println(e1.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e1) {
        System.err.println(e1.getMessage());
        return null;
    }

    Field[] fields;

    if (privacy == 0) {
        fields = classname.getFields();
    } else {
        fields = classname.getDeclaredFields();
    }

    for (Field f : fields) {
        // System.out.println("Declared " + f.getName());

        if ((privacy == 2) && (Modifier.isPrivate(f.getModifiers()))) {
            f.setAccessible(true);
        }

        try {
            if (js.has(f.getName())) {
                String type = f.getType().getSimpleName();
                if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("boolean")) {
                    f.setBoolean(obj, js.getBoolean(f.getName()));
                } else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("int")) {
                    f.setInt(obj, js.getInt(f.getName()));
                } else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("double")) {
                    f.setDouble(obj, js.getDouble(f.getName()));
                } else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("float")) {
                    f.setFloat(obj, (float) js.getDouble(f.getName()));
                } else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("string")) {
                    f.set(obj, js.getString(f.getName()));
                } else if (f.getType().isArray()) {
                    f.set(obj, Array.newInstance(f.getType().getComponentType(), js.getJSONArray(f.getName()).length()));
                    insertArrayFromJSON(f.get(obj), js.getJSONArray(f.getName()));
                }else{
                    f.set(obj, populateObjectFromJSON(f.getType(), js.getJSONObject(f.getName())));
                }
            }
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        if ((privacy == 2) && (Modifier.isPrivate(f.getModifiers()))) {
            f.setAccessible(false);
        }
    }

    return obj;
}
```

thanks

Comment: Sorry, why again are you re-inventing the wheel writing your own JSON parser?

Comment: hello @GhostCat because i am writing SDK and .aar/.jar  cannot have dependences from external libs. I know Gson is my best solution

Comment: The json you posted is missing the final closing brace }
You can validate it [here](http://json.parser.online.fr/)

Comment: @dalla92 its a sample json code. I will update it